# How to count occurrences of each character including upper and lower cases?

Tags: sorting, sed

I've been trying to count the amount of times that a character appears on a file by using the following code:

```
sed 's/./&\n/g' 1.txt | sort | uniq -ic
```

However, it doesn't distinguish between upper and lower cases. Here is an example:

The content of the file 1.txt is this: `hola Adios`

And this is the output:

```
1
2 a
1 d
1 h
1 i
1 l
2 o
1 s
```

As you can see, I have letter "a" and "o" 2 times, but the correct output should be this:

```
1
1 a
1 A
1 d
1 h
1 i
1 l
2 o
1 s
```

Just one time "a" and one time "A". Does anyone know how can I modify the code in order to have the expected output (to distinguish between upper and lower cases)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `uniq -ic` then? `-i` means *ignore case*, the manual clearly states that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do

```
sed 's/./&\n/g' 1.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

removing the option 'i' whose does not differentiate upper and lower case

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat 1.txt 
hola Adios
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ sed 's/./&\n/g' 1.txt | sort | uniq -c
      1 
      1  
      1 a
      1 A
      1 d
      1 h
      1 i
      1 l
      2 o
      1 s
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note one of the '1' alone is for the newline, if I remove it in the input file :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat 1.txt 
hola Adiospi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ sed 's/./&\n/g' 1.txt | sort | uniq -c
      1  
      1 a
      1 A
      1 d
      1 h
      1 i
      1 l
      2 o
      1 s
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the empty field separator in awk, you can parse one char at a time. The advantage is that you use only one process and avoid inserting a newline with sed for each character, as was your original attempt.

```
awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++}END{for (i in a){print a[i],i}}' 1.txt
```

[Although an empty field separator is not POSIX specified, it is a common extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html). Worked with `gawk`, `mawk` and `nawk`.

```
awk -F '' '                     #Empty field separator
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++}     #Each char has an entry in this array and is incremented when found
END{for (i in a){print a[i],i}} #Print number of occurrences and value
' 1.txt
```